# Using Linux, how would I find an image stored in base64 locally?

Tags: files, base64

I've been given a project handled by a former coder in our organization. It's a php based application and it is Massive (as in tons of files everywhere). I'm trying to find a logo that's stored...SOMEWHERE in this mess, so I can replace it with the updated (and properly oriented, this one is flipped for some reason) one.

I don't know know which file this is of even if it's stored as a file. The only reference I have when I run the app through localhost the file is referenced like this

```
data:image/png;base64,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```

Sorry I don't know how to make the above small - but yes that's the file I need to change to an updated one. Any help on how to FIND this file and or references to it would be appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That **is** the image.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: as I mentioned, yes that *is* the image I need to replace. My question is how do I FIND it? If this isn't a file then it must be a base64 string IN a file right? Is there a way to find that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for the decoded image, base64-decode it to `reference.png` and to

```
for file in `find /your/app/root/path -iname "*png"`; do
  if `cmp -s reference.png "$file"`; then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

If this doesn't find it, it maybe doesn't have a `png` suffix, so instead of `-iname *png` simply use `-f`. This may take a while though.

Not found? It will take even longer to search for the base64-encoded image by `grep`ing for a relevant substring:

```
grep -rI "WrOWqDHKv135ghOXbgIwsnsn2ycnGRheh" /your/app/root/path
```

Comment: That chunk is all header - might be better to use one from later on in the file (though the chances of having multiple 32x33 images around may be low).

Comment: Good point. Changed the piece

Comment: Just wanted to say I was able to solve this thanks to BOTH Philippos and @Tiggers answers. 

From Phillippos answer: grep was the key. 
From Tigger's answer: While the image weren't stored within <img> tags that did put me in the right direction. I eventually found the images stored within CSS files.

Thanks to both of you for answering the question! I sadly can only choose 1 tick mark and since there's a modicum of pedantry in this sub - I chose the answer that closest matched my (now edited) question. But again, Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the image is in a database or a utility / common page. Something that would be called on every page the image is on.

I would be looking for the code (PHP) that shows that logo. I'm also guessing it would be in an `include(...)` or `require(...)` file. Steps to find it:

- Open the source code for a few pages in an editor that has the image on it.
- Look for the `<img` tag. The tag is still required with base64 data images.
- Drill back from each `<img` until you find the code that renders the logo.

If you are lucky, there will be a comment block on how to change it. That is what I would have done :]